# JPA closes connection before creating JoinTable statement

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

there are 2 entities in my application - User and Role.
I would like to set up a unidirectional ManyToMany relationship.

My entities:

Role:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class RoleEntity extends BaseEntity {    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles = new HashSet<RoleEntity>();

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

The problem appears when trying to create a new User that has a Role.
I am creating a User like that:

```
//Role
RoleEntity adminRole = new RoleEntity();
adminRole.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
roleService.createRole(adminRole);
//User
UserEntity admin = new UserEntity("admin", "admin", "adminFirstName", "adminLastName");
RoleEntity role_admin = roleService.loadRoleByRoleName("ROLE_ADMIN");
admin.getRoles().add(role_admin);
userService.persistUser(admin);
```

Strangely, the right database entries are getting created even though I am receiving an Exception when JPA tries to write to the joined Table.
Stack trace:

```
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG SQL:104 - insert into users (firstName, lastName, password, username) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG IdentifierGeneratorHelper:93 - Natively generated identity: 1
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:173 - committing
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:147 - Processing flush-time cascades
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:188 - Dirty checking collections
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG Collections:190 - Collection found: [de.mato.main.entities.UserEntity.roles#1], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:121 - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:128 - Flushed: 1 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 1 collections
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG EntityPrinter:114 - Listing entities:
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - de.mato.main.entities.UserEntity{id=1, lastName=adminLastName, username=admin, roles=[de.mato.main.entities.RoleEntity#1], firstName=adminFirstName, password=$2a$10$OHRpnWfnHqIdsPUB2WGV1OUVdaVZ8tdSNsJ3DcaRK4cy3xOp1UMs6}
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1201 - Inserting collection: [de.mato.main.entities.UserEntity.roles#1]
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG SQL:104 - insert into users_roles (role_id, user_id) values (?, ?)
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper:294 - could not log warnings
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:466)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getWarnings(StatementImpl.java:2463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.handleAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.release(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.releaseStatements(AbstractBatchImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1256)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1159)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:496)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.persistUser(Unknown Source)
    at de.mato.main.ApplicationInit.createStandardRoles(ApplicationInit.java:60)
    at de.mato.main.ApplicationInit.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationInit.java:43)
    at de.mato.main.ApplicationInit.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationInit.java:1)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper:302 - could not clear warnings
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1023)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:466)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.clearWarnings(StatementImpl.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.handleAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logAndClearWarnings(SqlExceptionHelper.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.close(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.release(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:381)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.releaseStatements(AbstractBatchImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1256)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1159)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:496)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.persistUser(Unknown Source)
    at de.mato.main.ApplicationInit.createStandardRoles(ApplicationInit.java:60)
    at de.mato.main.ApplicationInit.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationInit.java:43)
    at de.mato.main.ApplicationInit.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationInit.java:1)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:773)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG JdbcCoordinatorImpl:512 - Exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout [No operations allowed after statement closed.]
17-10-2014 11:42:51 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1284 - Done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
```

I already tried to set up connection pooling but I am receiving similar exceptions.
Does anybody have an idea what I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: Could it be that you require a transaction to execute the multiple inserts (thats what i think the exception implies)

Comment: Try to do all together inside a `@Transactional` annotated method on a service instance. (example in `userService.createUserAndRole(...)`

Comment: Putting it all in one Method and annotate it as @Transactional doesn't work / throws the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the problem. Trying another version of Hibernate (lower than 4.0.2) works. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me as well. I was using the version 4.2.18.Final then lower it 4.0.1.Final and worked ok. But, I don't know to explain why. Anyway thanks for sharing.